# How to disable "uBlock Origin has prevented the following page from loading"?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, ublock

I'm using the Chrome browser extension uBlock Origin ([Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en), [GitHub page](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock)). It works to block ads and other elements on web pages.

However sometimes it blocks *whole pages* with the message:

> uBlock Origin has prevented the following page from loading

How can I disable this feature completely? It really annoys me.

Comment: can you give me an example, where I can try that? never encountered a page that was blocked completely by ublock (using it myself for some months now)

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann I'll post an example here when I next see one.

Comment: Here is an example which I encountered using the Enhanced Steam firefox addon: http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-6305441-10785951?URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamersgate.com%2FDD-FIGHTING-FANTASY-LEGENDS%2Ffighting-fantasy-legends%3Fcaff%3D3964022

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page itself has the solution: there are buttons in there which offers you to disable temporarily or permanently the whole page blocking (aka "strict blocking") for the current site.

If exposing hidden redirects and not connecting at all to dubious sites is less important to you than a once-in-a-while-with-easy-temporary-or-permanent-remediation "annoyance", then the [wiki documentation](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Strict-blocking) has the solution (add to the *My rules* pane):

```
no-strict-blocking: * true
```

Comment: Bad cut & paste from doc, the rule to add is `no-strict-blocking: * true`, not `strict-blocking: * true`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: The page itself does not always have the solution. Typically, no solution with this redirection: http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-6305441-10785951?URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gamersgate.com%2FDD-FIGHTING-FANTASY-LEGENDS%2Ffighting-fantasy-legends%3Fcaff%3D3964022

Comment: For info, the problem exists for uMatrix as well, and I could not find the equivalent of this wiki page (the one you linked to is for uBlock).

Answer (score 4):

#### uBlock Origin has prevented the following page from loading

uBlock Origin will block whole pages if the URL matches something in the Malware Domains list:

[image]

These domains are blocked by default:

> The default behavior of uBlock Origin when newly installed is to block ads, trackers and malware sites

You can unblock them (at your own risk) by white-listing the site or by unchecking the appropriate list.

You will then be able to visit the site in question.

Comment: Strict blocking is enforced for more than just the malware domains, it applies to any filter for which there is a strict hostname match. Un-checking filter lists or whitelisting is not the solution, disabling strict blocking for the current site (recommended) or everywhere (not recommended) is the solution.

Comment: While the other answer explaining how to disable "strict blocking" is very interesting, I think this answer is the most adequate. Indeed, i) one does not want to disable "strict blocking" globally, ii) for most cases, it is a filter which is the cause of the blocking, so there will be a temporary fix, iii) for the remaining cases, the cause of the blocking is in the HOSTS file, and it is smarter to disable "over-protective" HOSTS files which include false positives.

Comment: For the benign redirection which I encountered and which is blocked, the blocked host is present in two files: "Dan Pollock’s hosts file" and "MVPS HOSTS". The rest of the files, such as "Malware Domain List", do not include this host. This is likely a false positive and a sign that the two files listing the host are not serious enough to my tastes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually want to continue blocking the ad/page but not be informed that uBlock Origin did block it. You can block all popups from a webpage (read more [here](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Per-site-switches#no-popups))

Visual method

1. Open the site which has popups
2. Click the uBlock extension icon
3. Select icon which looks like two overlapping squares "Click to block all popups for this site".
   [image: Clicking uBlock Origin extension on site that produces popups with popup button selected]
4. Select the lock (that just appeared) to make this permanent.
   [image: Padlock to block popups permanently]

Manual method (useful if uBlock Origin on mobile):

1. uBlock Dashboard (Settings page) -> My Rules
2. Under the Temporary rules pane add a new line with
   `no-popups: url true` in this example you would use `no-popups: cimanow.tv true`
3. Press Save
4. Press Commit (to block popups permanently and will copy this to the Permanent Rules on the left hand side).

Comment: hi my dude your idea is great but my case i disabled the extension on the target page for it to work ... but  i am still getting the alerts from it .... can't i just disable them ?

Comment: No, it's strict blocking causing the alerts, so only way for you to not receive them at all is to disable strict blocking (check top answer on how to do that).  I would strongly advise you to NOT do that though. Most of those sites DO actually contain either malware or adware and if you don't have other protection systems in place, your computer will soon look like an old ladies laptop that facebook's and plays matching games xD

Comment: "so only way for you to not receive them at all is to disable strict blocking" 

not really i figured that i can instantly auto close the alert pages using an extension called Ad Close Gold but for some reason this activated the anti adblock script again even thought strict blocking info page said that using it 

"not a single connection is made to the remote server hosting the web page"

so I have concluded that the site anti adblock script doesn't care about the pop up at all but it looks that you still not in the page after the ad is opened for 3 seconds or something..

Comment: so i think the fix can be a delay although i don't know how to edit the extension ..... what do you think ?

Comment: You're making this way more complicated then it needs to be.  uBlock is opening a page telling you that it blocked the page due to strict blocking, that is technically a popup.  So add popup blocking in uBlock, whats the problem? Trust me on this one, if uBlock is telling you not to go to that site (strict blocking) don't go there it's not good for your OS's health

Comment: "if uBlock is telling you not to go to that site (strict blocking) don't go there" i am not going my dude it's just a pop up .... also adguard fixed the problem ... thanks for your suggestion.... pop up blocking wouldn't help as the site doesn't let me use it without disabling the ublock even if i tried to remove all the alerts..

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. Great job.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the order of your `$_GET` arguments.  Example of `$_GET` arguments that can force any page to be blocked....

> `?action=browse&`

Example Fix...

> `?blahblahblah=blahblahblah!&action=browse`

The coder of this "filter", so-called "EasyPrivacy", should most certainly not be turned on be default.  And yet, it is.